# Convert Query String to Object

Tags: vbscript

I'm working on a legacy application that is written in vbscript. Of which I have zero experience.

I have a function that returns a string

`{"Success":true,"CVVMatch":false,"Message":"Success","AuthCode":"010203","ResponseMessage":"Approved","PnRef":"AXXXXXX","ResultCode":0}`

How can I quickly parse through this string and create a usable object?

Should I use the `Scripting.Dictionary` object?

Comment: `Split` might come in handy, but this really depends on what you mean by "usable object".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a dictionary is probably your best option here.

1. Remove the curly brackets from the input string.
2. Split the string at commas to separate the key/value pairs from each other.
3. Split each key/value pair at the colon.
4. Add key and value to the dictionary.

Something like this should work:

```
str = "..."
str = Mid(str, 2, Len(str)-2)

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each pair In Split(str, ",")
  arr = Split(pair, ":", 2)
  If UBound(arr) = 1 Then dict(arr(0)) = arr(1)
Next
```

Comment: I had to remove the quotes as well on the keys so I could reference the dict.Item("Success") etc