# Pass patterns and corresponding replacement strings to function

Tags: arrays, vba, vbscript

I want to pass dictionary type array to Function using VBScript.

I want to make a regex function that can be run on such array.

For example

```
array = [pat1:rep1, pat2:rep2]
'or any valid VBScript array or dictionary format

txtLn = regs()

Function regs(array)
  Set regEx_ = new regExp
  With regEx_
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = True

    .Pattern = pat1:rep1
    txtLn = regEx_.replace(txtLn, replace pattarn 1 from array)

    .Pattern = pat1:rep2
    txtLn = regEx_.replace(txtLn, replace pattarn 2 from array)

    'and so on till the length of array

  txtLn = regs
End function
```

I know that this is broad question but I don't have any Idea.
What I expect is another Idea.
Please give me direction

Comment: VBA or VBS? Those are 2 different things.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I thought people who use VBA might also be knowing the answer as dictionary is also present in VBA (by adding references)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you really want to pass a dictionary, since you want to pass patterns mapped to replacement strings. Try something like this:

```
Function regs(d)
  Set regEx_ = New RegExp
  With regEx_
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = True

    For Each p In d.Keys
      .Pattern = p
      txtLn = regEx_.Replace(txtLn, d(p))
    Next
  End With

  regs = txtLn
End Function
```

Note that you need to assign `txtLn` to the function name to pass the result back to the caller. It'd also be good practice to pass `txtLn` as a parameter into the function instead of having the function operate on a global variable.

Comment: Thanks. Coming up next, How to convert string to dictionary so that I can make function that does both first add the string to dictionary and then execute replace.

Comment: like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913924/convert-query-string-to-object. Is this will be the best?

Comment: That's (obviously) what I would do.

Answer (score 1):

You said you need ideas - here is how I pass dictionary to a sub. In the example, I generate a Dictionary with keys the digits from 0 to 9 and I pass it to the PrintDictionary sub in order to print it:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub NumbersAndDictionary()

    Dim l_counter_0     As Long
    Dim l_counter_1     As Long
    Dim l_counter_2     As Long
    Dim l_value         As Long

    Dim my_dict         As Object
    Dim my_str          As String

    Set my_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For l_counter_0 = 65 To 76
        my_str = CStr(l_counter_0)
        For l_counter_1 = 1 To Len(my_str)
            l_value = CLng(Mid(my_str, l_counter_1, 1))

            If Not my_dict.Exists(l_value) Then
                my_dict.Add l_value, 1
            Else
                my_dict(l_value) = my_dict(l_value) + 1
            End If

        Next l_counter_1
    Next l_counter_0

    Call PrintDictionary(my_dict)

    Set my_dict = Nothing

End Sub

Public Sub PrintDictionary(my_dict As Object)

    Dim l_counter_0     As Long

    For l_counter_0 = 0 To my_dict.Count - 1
        Debug.Print l_counter_0; " "; my_dict.Item(l_counter_0)
    Next l_counter_0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me achiever first 15 reps then +1 to this.